# If there exists two component of same name, one in package and other in architecture, which one is given priority?

Tags: vhdl, hdl, modelsim

I have a VHDL test file a.vhd.

> > cat a.vhd

```
package pak is
component b is              -- 1st definition of component b.
end component
end pak;

use work.pak.all;          -- 1st definition visible through this package use clause
entity a is
  port (in1 : in std_logic );
end a;

architecture a of a is

component b                   -- 2nd definition of component b.
  port ( in11 : in std_logic);
end component;

begin
  inst : b port map ( in11=> in1);   -- there are two definitions of component b at this instance.
end a;

entity b is
port (in11 : in std_logic);
end b;

architecture b of b is
begin
end b;
```

So, when running modelsim on it, there was no warning/error of overridden component. Do we always give preference to the component, which is declared in the architecture over the component of same name declared in package. 
Can somebody tell me what does LRM say about it?
Please explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific example, the component you instantiate in "a" as "inst" is certain to be the component "b" declared in the architecture, because work.pak.b has a different port declaration.

If you instantiated a "b" with no ports in A, you should see work.pack.b.

Understand however that there is no inherent link between EITHER of these and "entity b". Only when the design is elaborated (e.g. at the start of simulation) will the tools look for a "b" that actually matches the component declarations. In this case it can find "b" declared in "a", but it won't find an entity matching "work.pak.b".

At this stage you can use configurations (either separate configurations, or configuration statements embedded in arch A) to bind a specific entity "work.b" to "b". This won't work with "work.pak.b" because of the mismatched port declarations.

Comment: Consider the case, when component b declared in package also has the same interface as the one declared in architecture. For this case, you are saying that at elaboration time, I should see work.pack.b.
 I want to know how is it decided to give preference to package component over the other? Is it tool specific or is this specified in VHDL LRM?

Comment: Sorry, I am NOT saying that you would see work.pack.b if the interfaces were identical. I expect the local "b". I can't point to an exact LRM rule that clarifies what happens, but it is a basic principle in other areas of VHDL (and its parent Ada) that a local declaration (e.g. a local variable) usually hides an equivalent but more remote declaration. In cases where two choices ARE visible (e.g. declarations of function "+" from different libraries) the convention is to hide both rather than make an arbitrary and possibly wrong decision between them.

Comment: Thanx Brian.In LRM 1076-2008 Section 12.4 Use clauses, states:

In order to determine which declarations are made directly visible
at a given place by use clauses, consider the set of declarations
identified by all use clauses whose scopes enclose this place.
Any declaration in this set is a potentially visible declaration.
A potentially visible declaration is actually made directly visible
except in the following three cases:

a) A potentially visible declaration is not made directly visible if
the place considered is within the immediate scope of a homograph
of the declaration.

Comment: So, yes. I have found the LRM rule as well.